# How can I create severals DF from factor label?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, split, automation

I'm pretty new to using R and I'm facing a problem. I have a general DF from which I want to create several DFs, one for each category of a factor type variable, also applying some condition. Do you know how I can do this?

The idea is this:

Gen_DF with, for example, a variable called "income" with labels "High", "Medium", "Low".

I want to get 3 more DF, one called High, other Medium and other Low, but adding a condition because the data has a lot of outliers for each category that I want to exclude (i.e., 95% percent of data for each category is ok). I know how do it one by one, but the problem is that my real DF doesn't have 3 categories but 21 and it's quite boring doing it one by one.

```
High <- Gen_DF %>% subset(income=="High") %>% subset(wages < quantile(wages, 0.95))
```

I need something like this but... automated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I base R we can use `split` to create a list of `data.frame`s. Below we supply `iris$Species` as factor to `split()` to get a list of three `data.frame`s for each factor level of `Species`. We can then filter each `data.frame` with `lapply` and `subset`. Finally, we can bind the list back together to one big `data.frame` with `do.call` and `rbind` if needed.

```r
iris |> 
  split(iris$Species) |>
  lapply(FUN = \(x) subset(x, Sepal.Length < 5)) |> 
  do.call(what = "rbind") # this line is optional in case we want the result in one df

#>            Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> setosa.2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> setosa.9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
#> setosa.12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> setosa.14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
#> setosa.23           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.25           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.31           4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.35           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.38           4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> setosa.39           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> setosa.43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> setosa.46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> setosa.48           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> versicolor          4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor
#> virginica           4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

The above can also be done in {dplyr}.

To get one big `data.frame` we use `bind_rows`:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length < 5) %>% 
  bind_rows

#> # A tibble: 22 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  5          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#>  7          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa 
#>  8          4.8         3            1.4         0.1 setosa 
#>  9          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa 
#> 10          4.6         3.6          1           0.2 setosa 
#> # ... with 12 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To get a list of `data.frame`s we use `group_map`:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_map(~ filter(.x, Sepal.Length < 5))

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1          4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  3          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  4          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
#>  5          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
#>  6          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
#>  7          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2
#>  8          4.8         3            1.4         0.1
#>  9          4.3         3            1.1         0.1
#> 10          4.6         3.6          1           0.2
#> 11          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2
#> 12          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2
#> 13          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2
#> 14          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2
#> 15          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1
#> 16          4.4         3            1.3         0.2
#> 17          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3
#> 18          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2
#> 19          4.8         3            1.4         0.3
#> 20          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1          4.9         2.4          3.3           1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with [automation](/questions/tagged/automation), my suggestion is to keep the data in a common data structure instead of creating individual (and individually named) data objects. A common data structure will allow for automation of subsequent processing steps.

The *split-apply-combine* paradigm is often used in data analysis, see [here](https://ramnathv.github.io/pycon2014-r/explore/sac.html) or [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v040i01/468), e.g.

It can be implemented in several ways. My preferred option is to keep all data in *one* data.frame as long as possible and to use *grouping* to process individual subsets rather than splitting and to process list elements.

So, OP's example to filter subsets by an individually computed threshold (95% quantile) can be implemented, for instance, using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) or [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length < quantile(Sepal.Length, 0.95))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 139 x 5
> # Groups:   Species [3]
>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
> # ... with 129 more rows
> ```

```
library(data.table)  
as.data.table(iris)[, .SD[Sepal.Length < quantile(Sepal.Length, 0.95)], by = Species]
```

> ```
>        Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
>         <fctr>        <num>       <num>        <num>       <num>
>   1:    setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
>   2:    setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
>   3:    setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
>   4:    setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
>   5:    setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
>  ---                                                            
> 135: virginica          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3
> 136: virginica          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9
> 137: virginica          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0
> 138: virginica          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3
> 139: virginica          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8
> ```

Note that the result still is a data.frame (or tibble or data.table, resp.) but now with 139 rows instead of 150. There is no call to `bind_rows()` required.

---

In order to verify which rows have been filtered out, we can show the 95% quantile for each group

```
as.data.table(iris)[, quantile(Sepal.Length, 0.95), by = Species]
```

> ```
>       Species    V1
>        <fctr> <num>
> 1:     setosa 5.610
> 2: versicolor 6.755
> 3:  virginica 7.700
> ```

as well as the outliers

```
as.data.table(iris)[, .SD[Sepal.Length >= quantile(Sepal.Length, 0.95)], by = Species]
```

> ```
>        Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
>         <fctr>        <num>       <num>        <num>       <num>
>  1:     setosa          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2
>  2:     setosa          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4
>  3:     setosa          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3
>  4: versicolor          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4
>  5: versicolor          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5
>  6: versicolor          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4
>  7:  virginica          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2
>  8:  virginica          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3
>  9:  virginica          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0
> 10:  virginica          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0
> 11:  virginica          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3
> ```

Comment: The problem here is that I need further analysis with this restricted data, and particularly with each group of income. That's why I prefer keeping the data in several data frames, one for each category, because there will be particular analysis for each category (I mean, there are variables in common, but I want to study them isolated by category). I appreciet your help (deep and very clear and useful) but I think that it isn't what I was looking for.